# query multiple unrelated tables

Tags: database-design, schema

Just learning mysql and db so guess this is a general schema design question.
Say i have 10 different types of widgets and each widget transaction has a date, amount and 8 other unique columns to that widget. First idea was to have one transaction table, but that would require 83 columns (Date, amount,widgetType,(+8 unique columns for each of 10 widgets). And only 11 columns would be filled in for each record. It works but sounds like a bad design, so my second though was to have 10 transaction tables for each widget type, much cleaner but i can't tie them all together.

Example

```
widget1 (date, amount,  *color, *wheelsize, *w1desc5, *w1desc6...*w1desc10)
widget2 (date, amount,  *power, *warranty, *w2desc5, *w2desc6...*w2desc10)
...
widget10 (date, amount,  *speed, *w10desc4, *w10desc5, *w10desc6...*w10desc10)
```

and i need a summary of all sales with just (date, amount, widgetType)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three approaches suggest themselves.

Unless you're really worried about disk space, sparse tables aren't all that great a problem - sure, you'll waste a few bytes, but in these days of Terabyte disks, is it really an issue? You could then construct views on your sparse table for the particular items.

You could also create 10 separate tables for your different widget types. You could then simply do a UNION/UNION ALL query to get Dates and Amounts and other queries for the particular widget properties (my preferred approach - different tables for different objects - and modern RDBMSs can cope with thousands of tables).

You could choose the [Magento](http://magento.com/) approach which specifically focuses on sparse tables by using the (normally anyway) antipattern of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) - it's big in clothing and the like where the number of styles, colours, shades and textures can be huge. See [here](http://karwin.blogspot.ie/2009/05/eav-fail.html) for the most eloquent image I've ever seen which brilliantly demonstrates a database principle.

Comment: Thnx yeah though these were my options wanted to make sure that i wasn't missing something

Comment: If you go with EAV I would suggest you store your common columns in your "E" table and only the unique ones in the "AV" part.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is subtypes where the common columns are stored together and the unique parts are separate.

```
widget  (id, date, amount)
widget1 (id, *color, *wheelsize, *w1desc5, *w1desc6...*w1desc10)
widget2 (id, *power, *warranty, *w2desc5, *w2desc6...*w2desc10)
...
widget10 (id, *speed, *w10desc4, *w10desc5, *w10desc6...*w10desc10)
```

Each transaction would have one row in `widget` and a corresponding row in `widgetN` *with the same `id` value*.

Summary queries can address `widget` alone.  Views can be defined to smooth out the separation:

```
create view widget2_view as
select
    date,
    amount,
    power,
    warranty
    ...
from widget as w
inner join widget2 as w2
  on w2.id = w.id;
```